# Question about how to read the notation in this song (Spinning song)

Tags: piano

What does the two ties mean in this context?
[image]

At the first tie am I supposed to hold down the C while playing the part marked with red and first let go of the C when I reach where the blue circle is?

[image]

Then there's this part i don't get at all. Wouldn't it sound completely the same without the tie?
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those aren't ties.  They're phrasing marks.  In the first case, it IS kind of confusing, since the arc goes to the same note.

Anyway, don't worry about it too much.  The rests pretty much force you to group the notes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Tie and phrase marks look remarkably similar. The difference is usually that tie marks tie together notes of the same pitch, often across barlines,(as it may seem here), while phrase marks will inevitably have a number of notes under them, with the start and finish notes being different.

Here, in the eight bars shown, the 3rd/4th and 7th/8th are definitely slurs, or phrase marks. However, I can see your dilemma in bars 1/2 and 5/6.Could be either. However, notes tied across a barline must be consecutive, with no other notes in between, and the 1st C is separated from the 2nd (bar 2) by two semiquavers, so it could only last a beat and a half, before the semis are played, thus making the next C a separately sounded note. But since the same timing and shape of all four are so similar, it seems more probable that bars 1/2 and 5/6 are also phrase marks. So, I'd be playing the Cs in 2 and 6 again, rather than holding them across the barlines.

So, in conclusion, there is not a single **tie** in the excerpt, only **slur marks** or **phrase marks**.

Be interesting to dig out any other publications of this music, to see what other engravers have done.

Comment: There's no way the first one could realistically be a tie.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - If you wrote your reasons why, it could be an answer.

Comment: @Tim - I thought the first one's first C not being a half note (i.e. doesn't take up the full measure) is enough reason that the first one cannot be a tie.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - true - the fact that the two Cs have something in between means they cannot be tied. Reflected in the edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim  Your edit has made things worse.  The fact that the 'tie' is across a barline is irrelevant.  And 'consecutive' doesn't mean what you seem to think it does!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - 'following one another without interruption'. I thought tied notes had to do that. I save up some of my bad days, but this is one that got away!

Comment: Ties can exist anywhere.  I disagree that "usually across bar lines" is valid.  A tie indicates (on any instrument, not just piano) that you do not re-attack the note; further one expects a slurred passage to have an additional curve indicating a tie within the passage.